# open sublime text 2 from terminal always pause the terminal

Tags: terminal, sublimetext2

I am running fedora 21, whenever i call "sublime" in terminal, a sublime window pops up but my terminal window also get tied up.

```
$ sublime

(sublime:2841): GLib-CRITICAL **: Source ID 2378 was not found when attempting to remove it
```

I cannot type any command at this moment and my terminal keep warning me this error message.

Does anyone has a solution?

I tried "sublime -n" and " sublime -w" but still works like this.

If i try " sublime&",i get:

```
$ sublime&
[2] 3252
$ 
(sublime:3209): GLib-CRITICAL **: Source ID 1378 was not found when attempting to remove it

(sublime:3209): GLib-CRITICAL **: Source ID 1741 was not found when attempting to remove it
```

Comment: what about sublime & ?

Comment: @Gerard Tried. No luck.

Comment: is the terminal still stucked wth & ?

Comment: yes, with & it still stucked but if i press enter it will get my terminal back, which is better but still annoying though. Never happen on my mac. but happen on every linux i've experienced